# using jquery to manipulating html table in Bootstrap, isn't working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table on a site I am working on. I used Bootstrap 3 for styling and navigation. I need to add data using jQuery, and to be able to do live searching once it has some data in it. Adding data dynamically doesn't seem to work for me in this case(or i cant make it work!!)

Here is the sample code, both html and jQuery:

html

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">

                    <div class="row  row-top-margin">
                        <!--min input-->
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
                            <input class="form-control " type="number" id="minAge" placeholder="Min.">
                        </div>

                        <!--Max input-->
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <input class="form-control " type="number" id="maxAge" placeholder="Max">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
              ..
              ..
              ..


        <div class="col-sm-8">
                <table  id="filter-table" class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
              ..
              ..
              ..
```

jQuery

```
 var people = [
        {name: "person1", age: 15},
        {name: "person2", age: 17}
       ];

var rows = [],
        $minValue = $("#minAge"),
        $maxValue = $("#maxAge"),
        $table = $("#filter-table");

function createRows() {
        people.forEach(function(person) {
            var $row = $("<tr></tr>");
            $row.append($("<td></td>").text(person.name));
            $row.append($("<td></td>").text(person.age));

            rows.push({
                person: person,
                $element: $row
            });
        });
    }
function addRowToTable() {
        var $tbody = $("<tbody></tbody>");
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            $tbody.append(row.$element);
        });

        $table.append($tbody);
    }
```

Comment: Since the code above is just a sample of your code, I took the liberty of adding a few lines and creating a bootply (see below).  I added a line which calls `createRows()` and a line in createRows which calls `addRowToTable()` and it seems to work.  If this does not work for you, please explain what activity you see versus the activity that you expect to see.  http://www.bootply.com/D4rJ32IqHw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, The code above will work correctly if form tags are removed from the code.

```
**<form class="form-inline" role="form">**
       <div class="row  row-top-margin">
           <!--min input-->
           <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
           <input class="form-control " type="number" id="minAge" placeholder="Min.">
       </div>

       <!--Max input-->
       <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
           <input class="form-control " type="number" id="maxAge" placeholder="Max">
           </div>
        </div>

**</form>**
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
jQuery('selector')
```

instead

```
$('selector')
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out this js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ndjuhjed/

The only thing I changed were your variable names, like `$minValue` to `minValue`. And it works, i.e. the values are added to the table. In jquery/javascript variable names should be simple descriptive names. You don't need the `$` prepended to it. That pattern is used in PHP.

On another note, if you are looking for live html table filtering you might wanna use jquery plugins like - https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

$minValue = $("#minAge");

if you want to get the value of "#minAge", you may do this

$minValue = $("#minAge").val();